# Show one div and hide the previous showing div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have some links that will show a div when clicking it. When clicking another link, it should show the link's associated div and hide the previously shown div.

HTML

```
<a href="javascript:unhide('text1');">Text 1</a> 
<a href="javascript:unhide('text2');">Text 2</a>
<a href="javascript:unhide('text3');">Text 3</a>
<div id="text1" class="unhidden"> 
    This will show up when the Text 1 link is pressed.
</div>
<div id="text2" class="hidden"> 
    This will show up when the Text 2 link is pressed.
</div>
<div id="text3" class="hidden">
    This will show up when the Text 3 link is pressed.
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function unhide(divID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
        item.className='unhidden';
    }
}
```

CSS

```
.hidden { display: none; }
.unhidden { display: block; }
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Try with:

```
function unhide(divID) {
    var unhidden = document.getElementsByClassName('unhidden');
    for (var k in unhidden) {
        unhidden[k].className='hidden';
    }

    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
        item.className='unhidden';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this :

```
function unhide(divID) {
    var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    foreach(var div in divs){
        div.className = 'hidden';
        if(div.id == divID)
            div.className = 'unhidden';
    } 
}
```

Be careful with `document.getElementsByTagName('div');`, it will return you all divs on your document. You could adapt it using a wrapper.

For example :

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="text1" class="unhidden"> 
        This will show up when the Text 1 link is pressed.
    </div>
    <div id="text2" class="hidden"> 
        This will show up when the Text 2 link is pressed.
    </div>
    <div id="text3" class="hidden">
        This will show up when the Text 3 link is pressed.
    </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
 var divs = document.getElementById('wrapper').getElementsByTagName('div');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/L79H7/1/:

```
    function unhide(divID) {

        var divIds = [ "text1", "text2", "text3" ];
        for ( var i = 0, len = divIds.length; i < len; i++) {
            var item = document.getElementById(divIds[i]);
            if (item) {

                item.className = divID == divIds[i] ? 'unhidden' : 'hidden';

            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also store in an array the names of the divs you want to hide and iterate over it when unhiding one:

```
var divs= new Array("text1", "text2", "text3");

function unhide(divID) {
    var item = document.getElementById(divID);
    if (item) {
        item.className='unhidden';
    }
    for (var i in divs){
        if (divs[i] != divID){
            item = document.getElementById(divs[i]);
            if (item) {
                item.className='hidden';
            }
         }
    }
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/7jRdG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need exactly links for this, but if you insist change it to:

```
<a href="#" onclick='unhide("text3");'>Text 3</a>
```

Otherwise you can change it to:

```
<p onclick="unhide('text1')">Text 1</p> 
<p onclick="unhide('text2')">Text 2</p>
<p onclick="unhide('text3')">Text 3</p>
<div id="text1" class="unhidden"> 
This will show up when the Text 1 link is pressed.
</div>
<div id="text2" class="hidden"> 
This will show up when the Text 2 link is pressed.
</div>
<div id="text3" class="hidden">
This will show up when the Text 3 link is pressed.
</div>
```

And your function should look like this to add or remove classes:

```
function unhide(id){
    yourElement = document.getElementById(id);
    if(yourElement.className == "unhidden"){
        yourElement.className = "hidden";
        }else{
        yourElement.className = "unhidden";
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[demo](http://jsbin.com/EpEMIlem/1/edit)

```
<div id="text1" class="hidden"> 1 </div>
<div id="text2" class="hidden"> 2 </div>
<div id="text3" class="hidden"> 3 </div>
```

```
.hidden{ display:none; }
#text1{ display: block; }
```

```
function show(id) {
    var item = document.getElementById(id);
    var all  = document.getElementsByClassName('hidden');
    for(var i=0; i<all.length; i++)all[i].style.display = 'none';
    if(item)item.style.display = 'block';
}
```

Answer (score -2):

you can use jquery try the code below and import the jquery library first

```
    $('#text1').show();
    $('#text2').hide();
```

it is the easiest way